# Ограничение целостности в связи многие ко многим

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

есть 3 таблицы:

1)Заказ (`OrderId`, и другие поля)

2)Продукты(`ProductId`,`Price` и другие поля)

3)Заказ-Продукт(`OrderId`,`ProductId`,`Count`,`PriceOrder`)

Заказ и продукт имеют связь многие ко многим и связываются через таблицу Заказ-продукт.

В таблице Заказ-продукт есть поле `PriceOrder`.

Есть так называемые "Вычисляемые поля", но данные эти никуда не сохраняются и если кто-нибудь в будущем поменяет цену продукта, то уже никак не узнать, сколько стоил заказ месяц назад.

Есть ограничение `DEFAULT`, но юзер при желании все равно сможет добавить свою цену, которая будет отлична от `Count*Price`.

Посоветуйте, как можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: По моему что-то намудрили с архитектурой. Обычно текущую цену привязывают именно к товару и при расчёте стоимости заказа берут значение актуальное на момент его оформления.

Comment: Я вот и хочу взять актуальную цену и проставить в таблицу Заказ-продукт. Для этого можно воспользоваться DEFAULT и в него заложить функцию, которая выполняла бы эти подсчеты, НО пользователь при желании все равно сможет вставить свою цену. Можно еще сверху повесить CHECK, который бы проверял:Если пользователь добавляет цену руками, то выполняется проверка равна ли она Count*Price . Насколько это правильно? Может есть что-нибудь лаконичнее?

Comment: Обычно цены выносят в отдельную таблицу привязанную к товарам. Это нормализует базу данных и позволяет избежать многих проблем с программированием.

Comment: А чем плоха моя реализация? В таблице Продукты храниться цена привязанная конкретно к товару, а вот в таблице Заказ-продукт храниться цена, которая была актуальная на момент заказа. Т.е к примеру в таблице продукты есть телефон, который стоит 1000. Юзер оформляет заказ на 10 телефонов и в таблицу Заказ-Продукт прописывается: Количество 10, общая цена 10000. Вроде, я все по разным таблицам распихал.

Comment: А, потом на эти телефоны меняется цена  и всё автоматически пересчитывается. Если цена неизменна с течением времени, вопросов нет. Иначе либо цены будут "перебиваться", либо придётся создавать дубликаты товаров. Как-то так. Именно поэтому, цены, которые могут измениться стараются выделять в отдельную таблицу.

Comment: Я как раз хочу добиться чего-то типа вычисляемого поля, но что бы оно не было доступно пользователю во время вставки и не менялось со временем. Т.е таблица Заказ-продукт будет проносить цены заказов сквозь время, независимо от изменения товаров в таблице Продукты. Может конечно мы друг друга, немного, не понимаем:)

Comment: От вычисляемого поля вы такого не добъётесь. Такого можно добиться, если использовать при добавлении хранимые процедуры. Но, повторюсь, используемое архитектурное решение для "торговой" бизнес-логики не самое удачное.

Comment: Если у вас пользователи имеют прямой доступ в базу, настраивайте им права в базе, хранимые пишите и т.д. Если пользователи в базу доступа не имеют (как в большинстве случаев), то решайте вашу задачу на клиенте: либо просто убирайте возможность редактировать суммы в заказе, либо разрешайте это правами...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен запрет на редактирование однажды введенной цены - то реализуется 
в порядке правильности:

1. Правами
2. Приложением
3. Триггерами на instead of update/delete